# Removing ending zeros with one simple preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, null, preg-replace, zero

i would remove the ending zeros with php_replace and i would have a better function like this.

Value:

```
$value = 123.12300;
```

Current function:

```
return preg_match('#[.,][0-9]+[0]+$#', $value) ? preg_replace('#[0]+$#', '', $value) : $value;
```

Another function:

```
return preg_replace('#([.,]{0,1}\d+)[0]+$#', '\\1', $value);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `return preg_replace('#[.,](\d*?)0+$#', '\\1', $value);`

Comment: `return rtrim(preg_replace('#([.,]\d*?)0+$#', '\\1', $value), '.,');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0-9]+`, `\d+` match greedily. (match as much as possible). It could match one of trailing `0`.  So use non-greedy version `\d*?`.

And `[.,]{0,1}` could make the pattern match even if that is no `.` or `,`. Just use `[.,]`.

```
$pattern = '#([.,]\d*?)0+$|[.,]$#';

var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, '\1', '123.12300'));
# => 123.123
var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, '\1', '1234000'));
# => 1234000
var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, '\1', '123456780.000000100'));
# => 123456780.0000001
var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, '\1', '123456780.'));
# => 123456780
```

Comment: Thank you. The mistake from me is the "{0,1}\d+" part... Hmm almost correct :)

Comment: Oh no... Try this number: 123456780.000000100. No effect!

Comment: Little mistake... Use this: preg_replace('#[.,](\d*?)0+$#', '\\1', $value)

Then it's perfect and the point/commata will be replaced, too. (Number: 123.)

Thank you.

Comment: `return rtrim(preg_replace('#([.,]\d*?)0+$#', '\\1', $value), '.,');`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `rtrim`:

```
return rtrim($value,'0');
```

Comment: This will also remove trailing zeros from `123000`.

Answer (score 0):

`rtrim()` will do the job

```
$value = 123.12300;
echo rtrim($value,'0');
```

Comment: `echo $value` will do the same thing since trailing zeros are removed from floats when printed anyway

Comment: Correct @ExplosionPills

Comment: This will also remove trailing zeros from `123000`.

Comment: falsetru> Then use this function only on non-integer values